# getting an access_token when third party cookies are blocked (FB.getLoginStatus returns unknown)

Tags: cookies, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an app in which I query /me/friends using the Facebook JS SDK. To do so, I need an access_token which I get using `FB.getLoginStatus()`.

If someone visits with 3rd party cookies disabled, `FB.getLoginStatus()` returns an `unknown` status (by design), and no access_token. How do others handle this? Is there another way to get an oauth token through the JS SDK? Do you just not load that feature, or do you fall back to a server-side method? Thanks!

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9930671/safari-3rd-party-cookie-iframe-trick-no-longer-working

Comment: Thanks. I ended up replacing the feature with a note about third party cookies if they are disabled. Not the most elegant of solutions, but it's not an essential feature and felt better than the workarounds I looked at. I may still fall back to a server-side method when I have more time.